# QuillJs : can't style text again after retrieving it from the DB

Tags: angular, quill

**Context :**

I'm currently using QuillJS with Angular 5 to register some rich text on my app.
The registration in the DB part is working well. I can retrieve the exact same styled text.

**Issue:**

But, when I try to format the text after retrieving it, quilljs, is like frozen: none of the buttons (police size, text color, etc.)  are working. Of course, there are no errors. I click on them but nothing happens. Those buttons do work if I just create a new text.

I can still put my selector in the text area and update a new (plain)text and retrieve it again.

Is it related to the way I'm instantiating the text with QuillJs with Get/Set Content function? It's the first time I'm using Quill, so I might be misusing it.

I can update more code if needed. Thank you very much for your help

Here is my code for my **text-editor.component.ts** :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-text-editor',
  templateUrl: './text-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./text-editor.component.css']
})
export class TextEditorComponent implements OnInit {
  quill: any = Quill;
  subscription: Subscription;
  subjectResetFields: Subscription;

  constructor(private textSvc: TextService, private passDataSvc: PassDataService) {
    this.subscription = this.textSvc.getTextFromDb()
      .subscribe(textToLoad => {
        // console.log('text to load', textToLoad);
        this.setContentIntoQuill(textToLoad);
    });
    this.subjectResetFields = this.passDataSvc.resetTextFieldConfirmed()
      .subscribe(f => {
        this.setContentIntoQuill('');
      });
  }

  // Homemade toolbar for the text editor
  // cf https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/
  toolbarOptions = [
    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],        // toggled buttons

    [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
    [{ 'indent': '-1'}, { 'indent': '+1' }],          // outdent/indent

    [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],  // custom dropdown
    [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],

    [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],          // dropdown with defaults from theme
    [{ 'font': [] }],
    [{ 'align': [] }],

    ['image', 'link']
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    // <!-- Initialize Quill editor -->
    const quillEditor = new this.quill ('#quill-container', {
      modules: {
        toolbar: this.toolbarOptions,
      },
      theme: 'snow'
    });
  }

  onClickSaveText() {
    const quill = new this.quill ('#quill-container');
    // jsonify and stringify the delta object from quilljs to allows it to be saved in the db
    let jsonifyDeltaText = JSON.stringify(quill.getContents());
    this.textSvc.postText(jsonifyDeltaText, this.passDataSvc.getCrId())
      .subscribe(answer => console.log('From save text button', answer));
    // update text in the service for later purposes
    this.getContentInHTML(quill);
  }

  setContentIntoQuill(content) {
    // turn back the registered text into Delta object in order to be well displayed by Quill
    const quill = new this.quill('#quill-container');
    const Delta = this.quill.import('delta');
    if (content !== '') {
      let reformatedContent = new Delta(JSON.parse(content));
      quill.setContents(reformatedContent);
      this.getContentInHTML(quill);
    }
    else {
      let reformatedContent = new Delta(content);
      quill.setContents(reformatedContent);
      this.getContentInHTML(quill);
    }
  }
```

**Text-editor.component.html :**

```
<!-- Include stylesheet -->
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.5/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Create the editor container -->
<form (ngSubmit)="onClickSaveText()">
  <div id="scrolling-container">
    <div id="quill-container"></div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <button class="btn btn-success float-right" type="submit">Sauvegarder le texte</button>
  </div>
  <br>
</form>

<!-- Include the Quill library -->
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.5/quill.js"></script>
<!--Plus html to docx library-->
<script src="../../../../../compte-rendu-app/node_modules/html-docx-js/test/vendor/Blob.js"></script>
<script src="../../../../../compte-rendu-app/node_modules/html-docx-js/dist/html-docx.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can try to initialize quill AfterViewInit()

Comment: @Dioux Hi Dioux ! I Thank you for answering. I tried your solution and the result is still the same.

Comment: and if you set content afterViewInit? else there is a good wrapper here --> https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-quill-wrapper

Comment: Mmh i'm not sure to understand how to do that with afterViewInit. Because the set content function is used when the user click on a button and not automatically at the loading of the page. Otherwise i could try with the wrapper but i must admit that i would like to avoid using it. I'll keep as a last resort.

Comment: if you don't call this.setContentIntoQuill(textToLoad); in your constructor and use the button, you still have a freeze?

Comment: @Dioux After some testing, i realize that the problem is coming from the setContentIntoQuill function. I didn't test well yesterday. I'm calling it twice during my click for 2 different reasons, that's why it was still freezing when just removing one. Anyway, i begin to think that the quill.setContents is the issue.

Comment: The problem is link to this line : `const quill = new this.quill('#quill-container');` He doesn't like i think to create a new instance to set the content. I'll work around that and post my solution

Answer (score 0):

So i find out the issue. I was creating to much instance of quill i guess. I can't remember why i did that in the first place.

So i create a new variable in my class (quillEditor) that i use to create an instance with OnInit lifehook. And then i reuse it in my functions, which is way more logical actually...

Here is my code for my ts file :

```
export class TextEditorComponent implements OnInit {
  quill: any = Quill;
  quillEditor;
  subscription: Subscription;
  subjectResetFields: Subscription;

  constructor(private textSvc: TextService, private passDataSvc: PassDataService) {
    this.subscription = this.textSvc.getTextFromDb()
      .subscribe(textToLoad => {
        console.log('text to load', textToLoad);
        this.setContentIntoQuill(textToLoad);
    });
    this.subjectResetFields = this.passDataSvc.resetTextFieldConfirmed()
      .subscribe(f => {
        this.setContentIntoQuill('');
      });
  }

  // Homemade toolbar for the text editor
  // cf https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/
  toolbarOptions = [
    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],        // toggled buttons

    [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
    [{ 'indent': '-1'}, { 'indent': '+1' }],          // outdent/indent

    [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],  // custom dropdown
    [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],

    [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],          // dropdown with defaults from theme
    [{ 'font': [] }],
    [{ 'align': [] }],

    ['image', 'link']
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.quillEditor = new this.quill ('#quill-container', {
      modules: {
        toolbar: this.toolbarOptions,
      },
      theme: 'snow'
    });
  }

  // To do : Create a message which say to the user that the header form data needs to be set first
  onClickSaveText() {
    // jsonify and stringify the delta object from quilljs to allows it to be saved in the db
    let jsonifyDeltaText = JSON.stringify(this.quillEditor.getContents());
    this.textSvc.postText(jsonifyDeltaText, this.passDataSvc.getCrId())
      .subscribe(answer => console.log('From save text button', answer));
    // update text in the service for later purposes
    this.getContentInHTML(this.quillEditor);
  }

  setContentIntoQuill(content) {
    // turn back the registered text into Delta object in order to be well displayed by Quill
    const Delta = this.quill.import('delta');
    if (content !== '') {
      let reformatedContent = new Delta(JSON.parse(content));
      this.quillEditor.setContents(reformatedContent);
      this.getContentInHTML(this.quillEditor);
    }
    else {
      let reformatedContent = new Delta(content);
      this.quillEditor.setContents(reformatedContent);
      this.getContentInHTML(this.quillEditor);
    }
  }

  getContentInHTML(quill) {
    // get the text from editor in html version then format it in a complete html doc
    let html = quill.container.firstChild.innerHTML;
    let finalHtml = '<html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head><body>';
    finalHtml += html;
    finalHtml += '</body></html>';
    console.log('HTML TEXT', finalHtml);
    this.textSvc.sendTextInHtml(finalHtml);
  }
```